# How to temporarily hide a presented View controller that is also presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a rather abnormal situation where I am presenting a view controller which is a UITabBarViewController that contains the bulk of my app.

There are times when I need to temporarily hide that main controller and all of it's 'stuff'. On my root controller I can hold a reference to my presented tabBarController and dismiss that with self.dismissViewControllerAnimated and then represent that when I need it. But the issue I'm having is that I'm loosing any viewControllers that are presented by the tabBarController itself.

Is there a better way to accomplish this, or a way to keep the view controllers presented by my tab bar controller from being dismissed?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a segue which presents something from the view controller that contains the tab bar controller over top it. Without know more about this, I can't give you much help. This will maintain the state of the tab bar controller.